# Solving Frobenius Norm Inequality with Moore-Penrose Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Then, for the Moore-Penrose inverse $A^+ \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, the following inequality holds:
$
\|AA^+ - I_m\|_F \leq \inf_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}} \|AX - I_m\|_F
$

My idea:

The Frobenius norm of a matrix $M$ is defined as $\|M\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |M_{ij}|^2}$.

Let $M = AA^+ - I_m$. The elements of $M$ are given by $(M)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} A_{ik}(A^+)_{kj} - \delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.

Now, consider $N = AX - I_m$ for arbitrary $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. The elements of $N$ are given by $(N)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} A_{ik}X_{kj} - \delta_{ij}$.

Substitute these expressions into the Frobenius norm inequality:
$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} A_{ik}(A^+)_{kj} - \delta_{ij}\right)^2} \leq \inf_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} A_{ik}X_{kj} - \delta_{ij}\right)^2}
$

I'm struggling how to continue my proof or do my previous steps make really sense.

Answer (score 3):

The nicer approach is to leverage things that you already know about the MP pseudoinverse. Here's an approach you might like.

Let $x_1,\dots,x_m$ denote the columns of $X$ and $e_1,\dots,e_m$ the columns of $I$. We have
$$
\|AX - I_m\|_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^m \|Ax_i - e_i\|^2.
$$
Now, use the relationship between the MP pseudoinverse and least squares solution, keeping in mind that selecting a matrix $X$ is equivalent to independently selecting columns $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Recall that $Me_i$ is the $i$th column of $M$.